# Error in PHP Ajax Code

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
<!DOCTYPE html>       // index.php file
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="Container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <div class="well well-lg"><h1>Chat Online With Friends</h1></div>
                    <button id="registerbutton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                    <button id="loginbutton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                    <form id="registerform">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Display Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="displayname1"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password1"/>        
                        </div>
                        <button id="register" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
                    </form>
                    <form id="loginform">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Display Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="displayname"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password"/>
                        </div>
                        <button id="login" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
                    </form>
                    <p id="result"></p>
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

$(document).ready(function(){              // script.js file 

    $("#registerbutton").click(function(){

        $("#loginform").css("display","none");
        $("#registerform").css("display","block");

    });

    $("#loginbutton").click(function(){

        $("#registerform").css("display","none");
        $("#loginform").css("display","block");

    });

    $("#register").click(function(){

        $display_name=$("#displayname1").val();
        $.post("process.php",{$displayname:displayname},function(data){

            $("#result").html(data);

        });

    });

});

<?php                                   // prcess.php file

echo $_POST['$displayname'];



?>


.col-sm-8{                                // style.css file
    background-color:aquamarine;
    min-height:200px;
}
h1{
    text-align:center;
}
form{
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    margin:auto;
}
.form-control{
    border:0 none;
}
.btn-default{
    border:0 none;
}
#registerform{
    display:none;
}
#loginform{
    display:none;
}
```

The question is when i try to submit the form ie register form and hit the     register button system crashes and nothing happens why it is happening because all the code is correct why it is happening as such?

Comment: Any error messages in the console or in the error log? Have you checked the network tab in your browsers development tools to see if it tries to send anything to your PHP-file? Have you dumped the request data to check that it looks correct? Please do some basic debugging and share the results.

Comment: Cannot see your Ajax functions

Comment: @PhpDev - The OP is using `$.post(...)` (with the wrong variables as the answer by JensV already pointed out) which does an ajax request using the POST method.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing the data in your ajax request. `displayname` isn't declared anywhere.

```
$("#register").click(function(){

    var $display_name=$("#displayname1").val();
    $.post("process.php",{$displayname: $display_name},function(data){

        $("#result").html(data);

    });

});
```

For debugging POST requests you can easily output any data in the request by typing `var_dump($_POST);` in your PHP Script.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are passing an object when a non-object value is expected. I ran your code and got js error:

```
TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement.
```

Problem is with the variable 'displayname':

```
$.post(...,{$displayname:displayname}...,
```

I tried:

```
  alert(displayname)
```

And got [object HTMLInputElement]. Maybe you want an actual value, but currently displayname is an object type.

Changing that to an actual value worked for me.